# inner-column labeled matrix

Tags: environments

I am slowly becoming more efficient with math environments and macros in TeX, but occasionally come across something where I'm not really sure what the best solution would be.

[image]

I wanted to hear from some experts what you think would be the most sensible approach (looks good and efficient to code) to making the above figure in LaTeX. I was initially thinking

1. `tabular` using `\multicolumn`,
2. TikZ; then
3. `array`.

Not necessarily looking for someone to just write me a solution, but more of insight into your macro/environment approach and why.

Comment: I would use a `tablular` or `array` environment for the textual portion and `tikz` for the drawing. Use `\tikzmark` to mark the points where the drawing will need to know where things age.  Plenty of examples of `\tikzmark` on this site.

Comment: is it necessary or useful for the displacement "markers" to be positioned at different distances from the equilibrium points?   this seems to me to be at least as much a diagram as something to be simulated by a table, and the distances, although not specific, are best shown as not uniform.  if so, the `picture` environment might be appropriate.

Comment: I have yet to explore either the \tikzmark or picture options and will have fun with them this afternoon. Picture looks very straightforward and appears to work much like \tikzpicture. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to favour the ordinary use of environments like `tabular` or `array`, since it makes the solution easily portable without any bells or whistles. Simplicity perhaps.

Based on the display, I'm going for an `array` with one column for the left hand descriptors, and 12 columns for the arrangement on the right:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{r@{\quad}*{12}{c@{\mskip10mu}}}
    & n-2 & & n-1 & & & n & & & n+1 & & & n+2 \\
    \mbox{Equilibrium:} & \bullet & & \bullet & & & \bullet & & & \bullet & & & \bullet \\
    & \phantom{{\leftarrow}}{\!|\!}{\leftarrow} & a & {\rightarrow}{\!|\!}\phantom{{\rightarrow}} & \\
    \mbox{Displaced:} & \ooalign{$\bullet$\cr\hidewidth${|}$\hidewidth} & & {|} & & \bullet & {|} & & \bullet & {|} & & \bullet & \ooalign{$\bullet$\cr\hidewidth${|}$\hidewidth} \\
    & & & {\rightarrow}{\!|\!}\phantom{{\rightarrow}} & \makebox[0pt]{$u_{n-1}$} & \phantom{{\leftarrow}}{\!|\!}{\leftarrow} &
      {\rightarrow}{\!|\!}\phantom{{\rightarrow}} & \makebox[0pt]{$u_n$} & \phantom{{\leftarrow}}{\!|\!}{\leftarrow} &
      {\rightarrow}{\!|\!}\phantom{{\rightarrow}} & \makebox[0pt]{$u_{n+1}$} & \phantom{{\leftarrow}}{\!|\!}{\leftarrow}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's verbose, but I like the straightforwardness of using just the array environment--it's easy for a newbie like me to understand. Is phantom the only solution for properly aligning tags under bullets?

Comment: Also, why did you use \makebox for the $u_{n}$ tags and not \multicolumn or something like that?

Comment: @BrazosWolf: No, you could probably also use a zero-width box for the one side that has an arrow. Something like `\rlap{$\leftarrow$}` and/or `\llap{$\rightarrow$}` without the accompanying `\phantom` (not tested). The zero-width box (`\makebox[0pt]`) allows the contents of box to be larger yet TeX still sees it as a `0pt` width box. So it helps condense things, since there's already a `\arraycolsep` gap between the columns.